# Nickelodeon or CN animated shorts from the early 2000

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I'm looking for a show that was composed of animated shorts. I think they aired between main shows or during ad breaks. They were on Nickelodeon or Cartoon Network, I'm not sure.

I remember that it was about 3 characters (2 boys and 1 girl) that went into a virtual world and fought against an Asian-looking villain that owned a cat. They used some kind of watch to transport or to transform themselves.

One of the heroes had glasses and his shirt was blue, the villain had an orange shirt and the cat was purple-ish.

The style was like 2d, like stick figures; it was very simple. I don't remember a lot about the plot.  It probably aired in the early 2000s or 2005.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [Oh Yeah! Cartoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh_Yeah!_Cartoons)  later followed by [Random!Cartoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random!_Cartoons). Produced by Frederator Incorporated and Nickelodeon. It was a collection of animated shorts by many cartoonists.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation of why this might match? Links rot.